# How to return javascript code result to the polymer custom element's <template>?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom, custom-element

#### SOLVED

I took the answer that @akc42 posted below and I added `var self = this;` before `getViews` function definition and changed `this` to `self` in code (and added `self` to the `ytr` like that `100 / self.ytr` as well)

#### /SOLVED

I'm trying to get view count from my youtube channel. All I want to do is to return calculated results back to the `<p id="views"></p>` and `<p id="youtubeRequest"></p>`.

I have this code:

```
<template>
   ...   
  <div>                      
      <p id="views" style="display:inline; ">100/Amount of views:</p>
      <p id="youtubeRequest" style="display:inline">Amount of views:</p>
  </div>
  ... 
</template>

 <script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'my-view1',

     ready: function()
     {
       function getViews(params) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&key=MyAPIkeyHere",
           jsonp: "callback",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(response) {
             this.ytr = this.$.youtubeRequest.innerHTML = response.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
             var ytr2 = this.$.views.innerHTML = 100 / ytr;
             this.ytr3 = ytr2.toPrecision(1);
             },
         });
       }
       getViews()
    }
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm using `this.$.id` instead of `document.getElementById("youtubeRequest")` since it is only used for accessing items outside of a Polymer element.

I need to bind calculated values to corresponding `<p>` tags

Comment: `response.items` must return `undefined`.

Comment: But what does it mean? I'm a newbie in web dev and I'm not sure what to do with it

Comment: What is the response, console.log it or something

Comment: It means it doesn't exist

Comment: @Un1 if you try to get a value that doesn't exist, you get `undefined`. That's it.

Comment: Google API dashboard says that it's a 100% Client errors. So it looks like it sending data but I don't know why it doesn't work and I don't know how to console.log it guys, any suggestions?

Comment: Firefox console says "response.items is undefined" but how am I suppose to define it. Doesn't it gets its value from the ajax request?

Comment: @Tobiq I updated the post please check it out

Comment: @vlaz I updated the post please check it out

Comment: why is `this.youtubeRequest` used? I'm sure that wouldn't exist in request function.

Comment: @Tobiq Well, I'm using `this.youtubeRequest` to get this `id="youtubeRequest"` from the shadow dom of that custom element. I can't get it just by `document.getElementById` inside the custom element

Comment: Your console says its `undefined`, you should use `document.getElementById("youtubeRequest").innerHTML;`

Comment: @Tobiq I forgot to say that it's not going to show up in Chrome if I'm using `document.getElementById` instead of `this.$.id`(I've updated the question one more time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above shows a closing `</dom-module>` but not the beginning.  Are you trying to define a Polymer element.

If so you just use databinding.  You can also use  to do the ajax call, but lets get the other bit working first.  Something like this

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
<template>
   ...  

  <div>                      
      <p id="views" style="display:inline; ">Amount of views: [[ytr]]</p>
      <p id="youtubeRequest" style="display:inline">[[ytr3]]</p>
  </div>
  ... 
</template>

 <script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'my-view1',
    properties: {
        ytr: {
            type: Number,
            value: 0
        },
        ytr3: {
            type: Number,
            value: 0
        }
    },
     ready: function()
     {
       function getViews(params) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&key=MyAPIkeyHere",
           jsonp: "callback",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(response) {
             this. ytr = this.$.youtubeRequest.innerHTML = response.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
             var ytr2 = this.$.views.innerHTML = 100 / ytr;
             this.ytr3 = ytr2.toPrecision(1);
             },
         });
       }
       getViews()
    }
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: ytr3 should already by ytr/100.  There was a typo in my example that had a space between this. and ytr3, just remove it.

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem! Just had to add `self` var to it